# sound clipping in windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, audio, sound-card

something is up with 64 bit version of windows 7.

i have 2 (good pro-sumer) sound cards which i've used in other version of windows 7 w/out problems, but now it is causing severe clipping noise (sound having little gaps surrounded by static)..

the cards i am using is echo mia, and native instruments audio kontrol 1.

the audio kontrol 1 is a external card, and would work ok for a few hours after rebooting, and than it would go back into clipping mode, to the point where you tube videos would not play from trying to process sound and it stopping for extended periods of time.

echo mia is performing better, but there is still some clipping and distortion.

the machine i use is newly built, with i7 920 64 bit cpu, 6 gigs of ram and an outdated nvidia video card (geforece 7950 gx2)

Comment: Do other external cards have problems?

Comment: one of the audio cards is internal

Comment: Got the same problem in Win7 64b with NI AK1. Win7 32b worked fine, always. I have powerful Dell laptop with Core i7 and nVidia NVS grapics with the latest drivers. I get sound clipping always after few hours of running the PC. I am getting mad... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrading my video card fixed this issue.